Function works when evaluated in the `*scratch*` buffer, but not when evaluated in an Org Source Block. Why?
Here is some code:
(eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x))
;; (require 'subr-x)

(defun mn:export-tree-as-string ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((src-tree (org-element-parse-buffer 'object nil))
     (id-mapping (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
     (final-tree (named-let f ((node src-tree))
               (let* ((new-node
                   (cond ((eq (org-element-type node) 'headline)
                      (mn:modify-headline-id-if-exists node id-mapping))
                     ((eq (org-element-type node) 'node-property)
                      (mn:modify-property-id-if-exists node id-mapping))

                     (t node)))
                  (src-children (org-element-contents new-node))
                  (new-children (mapcar #'f src-children))
                  (node-wo-children (org-element-copy new-node)))
             (apply (-partial #'org-element-adopt-elements node-wo-children)
                new-children))))
     )
    (org-element-interpret-data final-tree)
    ))

When I execute this code in a *scratch* buffer, and then run M-x mn:export-tree-as-string, it works just fine.
But when I put these definitions in an org mode source block (I'm doing literate programming), evaluate the block and then execute the function, I get:
let*: Symbol’s value as variable is void: --cl-f--

Any ideas why the named-let isn't working via Babel?

Found the answer. Apparently, named-let requires lexical binding to work. To enable this in the Org source block, I had to do this:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :lexical t
...
#+END_SRC

Now it works.
You can see details here. It seems they've put a check in named-let not to run if not lexically bound, but my Emacs is a bit older than the bug report.
